# Force firefox to download the video

Tags: html, firefox

I need to provide a download link to the user to download a video. When I visit the link using firefox, it starts playing instead of downloading.

How can I force firefox to download it?

Comment: are you linking the video or an embedded player?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set some HTTP headers. Example in PHP:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));    
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
```

Answer (score -1):

lol right click on link instead of left click and choose option save link as ..

Comment: I think the point of the question is to make left click to do the same as right click -> save as.